# RDCOMClient installation trouble on R-3.6

Tags: r, cran, install.packages, rdcomclient

I cannot install RDCOMClient, using R-3.6

Some background:
RDCOMClient works in my R-3.51 instance, and I need to use 3.6, and I need to use RDCOMClient to interact with my desktop's Outlook. mailR and sendmailR are not currently an option.

Thing's I've tried:

```
>install.packages("RDCOMClient")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/<user>/Documents/R/win-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘RDCOMClient’ is not available (for R version 3.6.0)
```

```
> library("devtools")
> install_github('omegahat/RDCOMClient')
Error: Failed to install 'unknown package' from GitHub:
  Timeout was reached: Connection timed out after 10000 milliseconds
```

```
> install.packages("RDCOMClient", repos = "http://www.omegahat.org/R")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/<users>/Documents/R/win-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository http://www.omegahat.org/R/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'http://www.omegahat.org/R/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘RDCOMClient’ is not available (for R version 3.6.0)
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository http://www.omegahat.org/R/bin/windows/contrib/3.6:
  cannot open URL 'http://www.omegahat.org/R/bin/windows/contrib/3.6/PACKAGES'
```

```
> install.packages("RDCOMClient", repos = "http://www.omegahat.net/R")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/<user>/Documents/R/win-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository http://www.omegahat.net/R/bin/windows/contrib/3.6:
  cannot open URL 'http://www.omegahat.net/R/bin/windows/contrib/3.6/PACKAGES'
Package which is only available in source
  form, and may need compilation of
  C/C++/Fortran: ‘RDCOMClient’
installing the source package ‘RDCOMClient’

trying URL 'http://www.omegahat.net/R/src/contrib/RDCOMClient_0.93-0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 49509 bytes (48 KB)
downloaded 48 KB

* installing *source* package 'RDCOMClient' ...
** using staged installation
** libs

*** arch - i386
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG -D_GNU_ -DNO_PYCOM_IPROVIDECLASSINFO -I.      -Wno-deprecated    -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c COMError.cpp -o COMError.o
COMError.cpp:347:0: warning: "_countof" redefined
 #define _countof(array) (sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]))
 ^
In file included from C:/Rtools/mingw_32/i686-w64-mingw32/include/combaseapi.h:129:0,
                 from C:/Rtools/mingw_32/i686-w64-mingw32/include/objbase.h:14,
                 from C:/Rtools/mingw_32/i686-w64-mingw32/include/ole2.h:17,
                 from C:/Rtools/mingw_32/i686-w64-mingw32/include/wtypes.h:12,
                 from C:/Rtools/mingw_32/i686-w64-mingw32/include/winscard.h:10,
                 from C:/Rtools/mingw_32/i686-w64-mingw32/include/windows.h:97,
                 from RCOMObject.h:23,
                 from COMError.cpp:1:
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/i686-w64-mingw32/include/stdlib.h:299:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define _countof(_Array) sizeof(*__countof_helper(_Array))
 ^
In file included from COMError.cpp:1:0:
RCOMObject.h: In member function 'virtual ULONG RCOMObject::Release()':
RCOMObject.h:61:50: warning: deleting object of abstract class type 'RCOMObject' which has non-virtual destructor will cause undefined behaviour [-Wdelete-non-virtual-dtor]
                                           delete this;
                                                  ^
COMError.cpp: In function 'void GetScodeString(HRESULT, LPTSTR, int)':
COMError.cpp:371:39: warning: format '%x' expects argument of type 'unsigned int', but argument 3 has type 'HRESULT {aka long int}' [-Wformat=]
  sprintf(buf, ("OLE error 0x%08x"), hr);
                                       ^
COMError.cpp: In function 'HRESULT checkErrorInfo(IUnknown*, HRESULT, SEXPREC**)':
COMError.cpp:409:51: warning: format '%X' expects argument of type 'unsigned int', but argument 3 has type 'HRESULT {aka long int}' [-Wformat=]
   fprintf(stderr, "<checkErrorInfo> %X \n", status);
                                                   ^
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG -D_GNU_ -DNO_PYCOM_IPROVIDECLASSINFO -I.         -O3 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=generic -c RUtils.c -o RUtils.o
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG -D_GNU_ -DNO_PYCOM_IPROVIDECLASSINFO -I.      -Wno-deprecated    -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c connect.cpp -o connect.o
connect.cpp: In function 'HRESULT R_getCOMArgs(SEXP, DISPPARAMS*, DISPID*, int, int*)':
connect.cpp:405:10: warning: variable 'hr' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
  HRESULT hr;
          ^
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG -D_GNU_ -DNO_PYCOM_IPROVIDECLASSINFO -I.      -Wno-deprecated    -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c converters.cpp -o converters.o
In file included from converters.cpp:1:0:
RCOMObject.h: In member function 'virtual ULONG RCOMObject::Release()':
RCOMObject.h:61:50: warning: deleting object of abstract class type 'RCOMObject' which has non-virtual destructor will cause undefined behaviour [-Wdelete-non-virtual-dtor]
                                           delete this;
                                                  ^
converters.cpp: In function 'SEXPREC* R_convertDCOMObjectToR(VARIANT*)':
converters.cpp:365:11: warning: variable 'hr' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
   HRESULT hr;
           ^
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++ -shared -s -static-libgcc -o RDCOMClient.dll tmp.def COMError.o RUtils.o connect.o converters.o -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.0/bin/i386 -lR
COMError.o:COMError.cpp:(.text+0x2b3): undefined reference to `vtable for RCOMObject'
COMError.o:COMError.cpp:(.text+0x4c3): undefined reference to `vtable for RCOMObject'
COMError.o:COMError.cpp:(.text$_ZN10RCOMObject7ReleaseEv+0x19): undefined reference to `vtable for RCOMObject'
converters.o:converters.cpp:(.text+0x175d): undefined reference to `vtable for RCOMObject'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
no DLL was created
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'RDCOMClient'
* removing 'C:/Users/<user>/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/RDCOMClient'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘RDCOMClient’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpc7CCRI\downloaded_packages’
```

I suspect RDCOMClient doesn't support 3.6, seeing as it's not in the directory here: http://www.omegahat.net/R/bin/windows/contrib/, but I figured I'd try here before I move on.

Is there anything I can do to get it working?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is not so, that RDCOMClient doesn't support R3.6. It only has not (yet) been compiled with 3.6x and been placed in the subdirectory of the current version in the repository "http://www.omegahat.net/R/bin/windows/contrib/3.6/". However the version 0.93-0 compiled with R 3.5x is fully compatible with R 3.6x, just download it from the 3.5 directory "http://www.omegahat.net/R/bin/windows/contrib/3.5.1/" and install as zip from your local PC.

Or do it directly

```
url <- "http://www.omegahat.net/R/bin/windows/contrib/3.5.1/RDCOMClient_0.93-0.zip"
install.packages(url, repos=NULL, type="binary")
```

Comment: You are a god amongst mere mortals.

Answer (score 2):

This work for me

```
library("devtools")
install_github('omegahat/RDCOMClient')
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that RDCOMClient doesn't currently support R3-6. To resolve this issue I have to switch to version R3.51 in Options to run RDCOMClient and send the e-mails.

It's not an ideal solution, but will do until they release an updated version.

Answer (score 0):

there is a package update at http://www.omegahat.net/R/bin/windows/contrib/4.0.0/ that worked for me (R-4.0.3).
Guess it should work for R-3.6 too.

Answer (score 0):

You can try accessing it from omegahet. It works perfectly

url <- "http://www.omegahat.net/R/bin/windows/contrib/3.5.1/RDCOMClient_0.93-0.zip"
install.packages(url, repos=NULL, type="binary")