# RDCOMClient trouble - program to connect to Outlook stopped working

Tags: r, outlook, rdcomclient

I have a program that searches some subfolders of my Inbox and downloads an attachment from daily emails, which is then used for analysis in R Studio. This program was working fine until this morning (it runs daily), and I did not make changes yesterday. I am using R 3.6.1, but had downloaded the package version for >= 3.5 since the package wasn't compiled for >= 3.6. This SO question helped me install it: [RDCOMClient installation trouble on R-3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56876003/rdcomclient-installation-trouble-on-r-3-6). I've also uninstalled RDCOMClient and reinstalled with this package version below, but it doesn't seemed to have helped.

`devtools::install_github("dkyleward/RDCOMClient")`

The code I am having problems with is below. It seems that RDCOMClient isn't able to connect to the relevant folder. The path to the relevant subfolder is 
[FirstName].[LastName]@companyemail.com > Inbox > Automated Reports, thus the folder definition below.

```
library(RDCOMClient)

Outlook <- COMCreate("Outlook.Application")

Inbox = "Inbox"
folderName = "Automated Reports"
outlookNameSpace <- Outlook$GetNameSpace("MAPI")
folder <- outlookNameSpace$Folders(1)$Folders(Inbox)$Folders(folderName)
folder$Name(1)
```

The error I get follows defining folder in the code above, and it is not particularly descriptive in solving the issue. The only thing I can think of is that this my work computer, so it's possible there have been security updates overnight that have not allowed RDCOMClient functions to work with Outlook.

```
No support for InterfaceSupportsErrorInfo
checkErrorInfo -2147352567
Error: Exception occurred.
```

Another thing I will mention in case it is helpful is that RDCOMClient tries to load when I restart R. Even when I've manually deleted the package, R/R Studio still tries to load it and displays the error below. This is the only R package I have installed for which this happens, so I'm not sure if this is something unique to RDCOMClient, or if this is an indication that the package is corrupted in some way.

```
Error in .requirePackage(package) : 
  unable to find required package ‘RDCOMClient’
In addition: Warning message:
In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
  there is no package called ‘RDCOMClient’
```

Any help or insight is appreciated; thank you.

Comment: *This program was working fine until this morning (it runs daily)*...Did anything change between yesterday and today? Maybe your IT changed email servers? Maybe you updated Office or Windows or R? Maybe you added a new Outlook account? Maybe folder was moved, deleted, renamed? Comment out lines to see problematic issue. Also, check if translated code works in Outlook VBA. Very hard on our end to help.

Comment: Re last item, check your `.RProfile` to remove any requirements of `RDCOMClient`.

Comment: thanks for your comments. Apparently the folder path structure did change for some reason (the firstname.lastname@companyemail.com  is now the 3rd folder as opposed to the first that it was as of yesterday morning), and i updated the program accordingly. I should be able to change my code so i don't run into that issue again.