# Batch convert Excel files to PDFs in R

Tags: r, excel, rstudio

I have a folder of excel (xlsx) sheets that I want to convert to PDFs in R. I've tried reading the worksheets into R directly (using almost all packages) but the data is never read properly. I'm dealing with excel spreadsheets from several different people so assume this is because of the differences between saving files from everyone's computers.

I figure that converting these files to PDFs would mean that they are all formatted the same and therefore will be easier to work with.

Is it possible to convert files from excel worksheets to PDFs using R without opening the files/reading them into R as this is where the errors occur?

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30942927/print-save-excel-xlsx-sheet-to-pdf-using-r

Comment: @captcoma RDCOMClient isn't available for my version of R (3.6.2) and the second answer has data read into R so unfortunately, this isn't what I'm looking for.

Comment: A compatible version of RDCOMClient is available from omegahat.net. Check out the script below.

Answer (score 0):

This should work with R 3.6.2:

```
# install RDCOMClient for 3.6.2
url <- "http://www.omegahat.net/R/bin/windows/contrib/3.5.1/RDCOMClient_0.93-0.zip"
install.packages(url, repos=NULL, type="binary")

# install R.utils
install.packages("R.utils")

library(RDCOMClient)
library(R.utils)

# make a list of the folder with your excel files
# replace "Path to your folder" with the path to your folder
list.files("Path to your folder",full.names=TRUE) -> list

# Batch convert (replace "Path to your folder" with the path to your folder)
lapply(list, function(x) {

file <- x                             # path to Excel file
ex <- COMCreate("Excel.Application")  # create COM object
file <- getAbsolutePath(file)         # convert to absolute path
book <- ex$workbooks()$Open(file)     # open Excel file
sheet <- book$Worksheets()$Item(1)    # pointer to first worksheet
sheet$Select()                        # select first worksheet
ex[["ActiveSheet"]]$ExportAsFixedFormat(Type=0,    # export as PDF
                                        Filename=paste0("Path to your folder",gsub(pattern = "\\.xlsx$", "", basename(x)),".pdf"), 
                                        IgnorePrintAreas=FALSE)
ex[["ActiveWorkbook"]]$Save()         # save workbook
ex$Quit()                             # close Excel
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I get `Error: Exception occured.` I ran `browser()` through the loop and figured out it raises the exception at `sheet$Select()` @captcoma

Comment: Did you try it on a smaller subset of your files? Probably one of your documents is corrupt.

Comment: which operating system do you use?

Comment: I'm using Windows 10 :)

Comment: try: `sheet <- book$Worksheets(1)`

Comment: or leave `sheet$Select()` out

Comment: Leaving in `sheet$Select()` gives the same exception, but taking it out and only leaving in `sheet <- book$Worksheets(1)` gives me a popup error here:  https://ibb.co/3CfZSnD

Comment: I'm also getting `<checkErrorInfo> 80020009 `

Comment: The code above works for me. Cannot figure out what is going on.