Convert/Save Excel File to PDF in R
I have several files that needs converting to PDF format. I wasn't able to find the solution to my problem anywhere, even with help of ChatGPT.
There was an idea of using RDCOMClient package, however this doesn't seem to work with the newest version of R (R version 4.4.1)
Do you know how to sort this out? I have an object (list) with 50 Excel files (modified and ready to become PDFs).
Thank you in advance.
# Construct the file path to save the workbook
  file_path <- file.path(reports_folder, paste0(student_name, " Attendance Report ", ".xlsx"))

# Save the workbook to an Excel file in the specified folder
  saveWorkbook(wb, file = file_path, overwrite = TRUE)

}

This is the last 2 lines of my code to save my work to Excel.

When you say "converting [excel] to PDF", what do you mean? Do you mean something like when you click print in Excel and print a worksheet?

You could read the excel files into data.frame's and render PDFs based on them via rmarkdown.

You can follow the guidelines given by @ismirsehregal if you wish to have it automated and don't want to spend a bit of time on pretty formatting. However there are kable and kableExtra packages which helps (https://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/awesome_table_in_pdf.pdf). On the other hand, if your excels are "pretty" formatted already, with borders/colors/backgrounds, the easiest way would be to install PDF printer driver (or Postscript printer driver, then GS) and print them directly using excel/libreoffice. Or create raport template in rmarkdown, import excel data and render it to pdf.

Did you try https://stackoverflow.com/q/30942927/1100107?
